# Two game object efficient and fast on-off switch

Tags: unity, loading

I have two game-object, on GUI button click i am toggle between them but the problem is one game-object which is small contains less vertx etc., is loading fast while the other which heavy taking time. How do i efficiently and quickly load it ? I don't want to show loading window i want to load that game-object quickly?

Comment: How exactly do you "toggle" between them? There are many different ways how you can make one thing disappear and another thing appear in Unity.

Comment: its so simple man! its  setActive function

Comment: That's odd. I always thought that inactive game objects are fully loaded and activating them is just flipping a switch to enable all their components. Do you maybe do something CPU-intense in `OnEnable` in some of its components?

Comment: nothing i am doing like that actually gameobject is heavy this is the problem and as i mention i want on/off gameobject not load unload as mention in question so it is not odd.